# Issue in setting active state of a link

Tags: jquery, css

I am having a [sample menu demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pEbt5/).

The effect is as desired in the demo. But when I apply the same in my website with `href="#"` getting replaced by `href="XXX.aspx"`, the effect is not as desired. Nothing seems to be working.

Can anybody help me as to where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that is the only difference?

Comment: @bažmegakapa , no I realized that the class active doesnot get removed

Comment: Well, that is because `a`s are not siblings to each other. They are within `li`s.  `$(this).closest('ul').find('a').removeClass('active');` should work.

Comment: @bažmegakapa , so what can I do to achieve that.

Comment: @bažmegakapa that din't work.

Comment: It works. Of course you have to change the order. [See the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pEbt5/1/). Still we are not closer to real problem: why your code does not work with a different `href`. There **must** be some more differences.

Comment: @bažmegakapa , ya it worked thanks for that but I dont know for a different href it doesn't work

Comment: You are the only one here seeing both codes. We can only see the demo that works. You either show an example that does not work, or try telling us what else can be different. I see no other way.

Comment: @bažmegakapa , the rest is working well , the problem is for a different href , the page gets refreshed and doesnt show the effect.

Comment: @bažmegakapa , Somebody told me that when href is set to something other than # , all CSS and .js file are reset , that is the reason the styles dont get displayed , is it correct.

Comment: @bažmegakapa thanks a lot , i found my answer , I have posted it.Thanks

Comment: Should make no difference, the `href` value has nothing to do with styles and JS. But whatever works for you :). I suspect that you forgot to prevent the default event of the link, which is navigating to the site in the `href`. Your thing worked, but you could not see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thing worked well for me.

```
$('#Menu ul li a').each(function() {
    var path = window.location.href;
    var current = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    if (url == current) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    };
});
```